# How to create custom view and apply UICollisionBehavior to it UIKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have shape of castle and want to detect collisions but it have SGRect path, so how can I make custom shape collision?

I have created custom view but it work partially, sometimes it detects collision but mostly another object goes through it.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.